# Use of "took its flight"

Tags: word-choice

Can I say: the use of specific models "took its flight" with the development of a specific theory, meaning that the models were used more often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "took its flight" is not really a regular expression, but sounds like "took flight", which usually means "ran away". What you are looking for is something like **took off**, which means *started to happen a lot* etc.

However, **took off** is more colloquial than formal English. A more formal phrase would be something like "the use of specific models **gained in popularity** …", or perhaps **became more widespread** and so on. It depends on what exactly you're trying to say.

Comment: "Took flight" is sometimes used, in reference to a theory, etc,  to mean that it "got off the ground", due to some reinforcing observation, say.